# game start lagging after adding background pygame

Tags: pygame

When i was making background with screen.fill, my code was checking collision of hero with a lot of projectiles - and program still wasn't lagging. But when i decided to add drawn background (3600x1200 pix) as sprite, and fps fell down to about 20 fps. I removed all projectiles, but fps is still enormously low. Such big background was chosen for moving it, instead of moving main hero. Here is my code and the problematic line displaying the background (everything works fine without it).

```
#import modules
import pygame as pg
from hero import Hero
#self-made classes
from obstruction import Obstruction
from setting import Settings
import gf
from time import sleep
**from back_ground import Background**
from command_block import Command_Line
#main function
def run_game():
    #pygame activation
    pg.init()
    #window settings
    settings = Settings()
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((settings.screen_width,settings.screen_height))
    pg.display.set_caption(settings.caption)
    hero = Hero(0, 0, "Right", 1/240, pg.image.load('images/hero/hero1.png'), 128, 16, 15, 0.08, 0.2, settings,27)
    bg = Background('images/sky.png', [0,0])
    cl = Command_Line(hero)
    #class creating
    projectiles = []
    #here was some projectile creating
    #variables initialization etc.
    work=True
    myfont = pg.font.SysFont('TimesNewRoman',int(settings.screen_width*0.025))
    #main loop
    while work:
        sleep()
        hero.is_running = False
        hero.idle = True
        gf.check_events(hero, projectiles, settings, cl)
        gf.jump(hero, projectiles)
        #updating hero rect due to coordinate changing and hero image due to direction changing
        hero.update_rect()
        hero.orientation()
        #screen filling with backgroung color
        screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
        screen.blit(bg.image, bg.rect)
        #displaying projectiles(walls,floor,etc.)
        for projectile in projectiles:
            projectile.display(screen)
        #displaying hero image and all his atributes
        hero.display(screen, myfont)
        gf.command_block_draw(settings,myfont,screen,cl)
        #test string for displaying problematic variables
        gf.test_string_draw(settings,myfont,hero,screen)
        #display updating
        pg.display.flip()
    #quit
    pg.quit()

#running game
run_game()
```

Line:

```
screen.blit(bg.image, bg.rect)
```

BackGround class:

```
import pygame as pg

class Background(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location
```

Comment: p.s. removing 'screen.fill' does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to convert() the image.

Changing this one line of code should increase your performance substantially.

It processes the Surface into a format pygame likes up front, speeding up all the consequent blits.

`self.image = pg.image.load(image_file).convert()`